# Expression.Call with MethodInfo and generic type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, expression

How can I use Expression.Call with MethodInfo and generic type arguments? 
Only the overloading with methodName has typeArguments.

```
var methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("OutputTypeName");          
var expression = Expression.Call(methodInfo);
Expression.Lambda<Action>(expression).Compile()();

public static class MyClass
{
    public static void OutputTypeName<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod:

```
var methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("OutputTypeName");
var genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
var expression = Expression.Call(genericMethodInfo);
...
```